# Independent Private Sessions

Tags: php, session

I need to manage multiple sessions in a website. I need to start a private sessions which is very page specific so it will terminate once I walk away from the page. But When I browse to previous page, i should be able to use my old session also. For example:

```
Page A -> Starts Session A
Page A -> is forwarded to Page B

Page B -> Start its own private Session B
Page B -> Completes the tasks and Terminates its private session B
Page B -> Redirects to Page A

Page A -> Again display the page using its old Session A
```

Can I start multiple sessions within a same website like this? If yes, How can I manage this?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [session_name](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-name.php) for this, but if page B is killing its session as soon as a single page view is complete, it seems like a waste of time to use a session in the first place.

Comment: Page B, will kill the session once the entire process is complete. Just a plain load of Page B will not do anything.

Comment: I saw few examples from your link, one of them was relying on cookie. Relying on cookie will compromise everything. Do you have any other ideas !

Comment: Storing the session is in a cookie are how sessions work (except when they shove the session id in the query string). There aren't any other ways to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps something like;

```
$_SESSION[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']]['name'] = $value;

//Page X termination
unset($_SESSION[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']]);
```

Just tersely tossing out ideas here.

---

Expanding on the privatization of session data; A wrapper could help:

```
class Session implements ArrayAccess{

    private $_data = array();

    public function __construct(){
        $this->_data = $_SESSION;
    }

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value){
        $this->_data[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']][$offset] = $value;
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset){
        return isset($this->_data[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']][$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset){
        unset($this->_data[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']][$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetGet($offset){
        return isset($this->_data[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']][$offset])
            ? $this->_data[$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']][$offset]
            : null;
    }

    public function __destruct(){
        $_SESSION = $this->_data;
    }

}

$session = new Session;
//etc
```

Given the query string or more is relevant, you could hash the relevant values for the key.

Eg: `$key = md5($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] . $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);` though using `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` as a key may suffice.

Comment: Yeah.... I thought about this... But all pages have access to this session so.... Not exactly what I am trying to achieve. Thanks Anyway :D